# send arguments to function from different places?

Tags: php, pdo

I have a function that fetch som user values. username and email.

now i would like the values to echo out in two form fields.

is that posible or do I need two different functions ?

Im thinkig about something like this

```
        function fetch_user_value($username,$email){
        global $db;
        $query = $db->query("SELECT `username`,`email` FROM `user` WHERE id = {$_SESSION['uid']} ");
        $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo $row['username'];
        echo $row['email'];
        } 

    <input type='text' name='username' id='username' value="<?php echo fetch_user_value('username'); ?>" />


<input type='text' name='email' id='email'  value="<?php echo fetch_user_value('email'); ?>" />
```

Comment: If the php and html markup are in the same document, you can just set variables and echo those in the `value` tags.

Comment: @Pankrates yes thats what i used first, but its more nicer to have them in functions :)

Comment: Ah ok, then look I would suggest @user868766 solution for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

//removed the parameters you passed, as you are fetching values on the basis on sessionid only

```
function fetch_user_value(){
  global $db;
  $query = $db->query("SELECT `username`,`email` FROM `user` WHERE id = {$_SESSION['uid']} ");
  $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  return $row;
}
```

// instead of calling it twice, call it only single time

```
$userD = fetch_user_value();

<input type='text' name='username' id='username' value="<?php echo $userD['username']; ?>" />
<input type='text' name='email' id='email'  value="<?php echo $userD['email']; ?>" />
```

Comment: aaa thank you, of course i don't need the parameters then :)

Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

Although user868766's answer is correct, consider making such a function more useful.
A general purpose one, to return desired result out of arbitrary query:

```
$user = $db->getRow("SELECT username,email FROM user WHERE id =?i",$_SESSION['uid']);
```

With good abstraction library you won't need no designated function for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just use one function, this way:

```
  function fetch_user_value($field){
     global $db;
     $query = $db->query("SELECT ".$field." FROM `user` WHERE id = {$_SESSION['uid']} ");
     $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     echo $row[$field];
    }
```

Comment: it is extremely bad practice to echo anything right from the function. make it return value, not echo. and this approach is potentially insecure. and the OP asked to return 2 values, not one.